# WMI escape characters on string variable programatically

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

i have this working query

```
ManagementObject pnpdevice = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
"select * from Win32_PnPEntity where DeviceID='{0}'",
"USB\\\\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_00\\\\6&48E0D58&0&0000")).First();
```

where i just realized that i needed to use quadruple slashes for one slash: two to escape in c#, two to escape in wmi.

my problem is how to do this programmatically instead of by hand. typically i would of course use the `@` in front of the string to escape, so this works as well:

```
ManagementObject pnpdevice = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
"select * from Win32_PnPEntity where DeviceID='{0}'",
@"USB\\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_00\\6&48E0D58&0&0000")).First();
```

but how do i do that with a string variable?

```
ManagementObject pnpdevice = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
"select * from Win32_PnPEntity where DeviceID='{0}'",
device["DeviceID"].ToString())).First();
```

this doesn't have any of the escapes i need, and fails as an invalid query. writing it `@device["DeviceID"].ToString()` does not work.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm dumb, it was easy, just needed to add a replace to the string.

```
ManagementObject pnpdevice = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
    "select * from Win32_PnPEntity where DeviceID='{0}'",
    @device["DeviceID"].ToString().Replace("\\", "\\\\") )).First();
```

Comment: Just FYI, this would never work. `ManagementObjectSearcher` is not a collection and does not inherit `IEnumberable`, so you can't call `First()`.